# How do I get the original request URL inside the base conttoller?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, request

I have an ASP.NET Core application which has a base controller. Inside the base controller, I use the OnActionExecutionAsync overridden method to re-direct the user to an external URL if a condition matches and when I call the redirect URL I also pass the original URL as parameter. 
How can I get the original request URL from my base controller, or more specifically from the OnActionExecutionAsync method of my controller?

Comment: Loot into `HttpContext.Request` there are `HttpContext.Request.PathBase` and others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anywhere in the controller you have access to the `Request` property, which contains all the components of the requested URL. It's not clear what *exactly* you need, but there's the usual suspects of `Scheme`, `Host`, `Path`, `QueryString`, etc. If you're looking for the full URL. You can use `UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl(Request)`.